# Xcode: gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, oolong-engine

I'm working on a game for the iPhone where I use the **Oolong engine** for rendering, and now I just tried to update my project to the newest version.

However, now I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

In the build results I see in which cpp file the error happens, but I don't see any additional information.

How can I get more info about what is going wrong in order to track down the problem?

**EDIT**

After inspecting the compile output, i got the following lines, where the error occurs:

```
{standard input}:61:selected processor does not support 'fmrx r0, fpscr'

{standard input}:62:unshifted register required -- 'bic r0,r0,#0x00370000'

...somemorelines

{standard input}:69:selected processor does not support 'fmxr fpscr,r0'
```

This is some VFO code from one of the `#include` files. It works fine in the examples that come with the engine. Could there be something screwed up with my project settings? I compared them to the one of the examples and they seem to be identical.

Comment: Xcode comes with gcc-4.0 and gcc-4.2.  How are you managing to use gcc-4.1? Is it installed with the Oolong engine?

Comment: typo :) i resolved the problem - my target settings have overwritten the 'compile for thumb' setting and i didn't notice it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Build->Build Results or hit shift-command-B. There's an icon on the far right of the error message that looks like a bunch of horizontal lines. Click that or select "all messages".

You may also want to edit your preferences in Xcode to always show the Build Results while the build is going on, and only hide the window if there are no errors or warnings. that's what I do.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error before, and the problem was that some files were deleted from disk and still referenced from the XCode project. Once I deleted those references, it worked.

This is a big limitation of XCode, it should really have shown a basic 'could not open file' message instead of this cryptic error message.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem.  in my case, the problem was that the same file was referenced twice in the Project Navigator (in different folders), leading to its being listed twice in Build Phases -> Compile Sources ...i think this happened when i re-generated managed subclasses of a core data model.

deleting the redundant reference in the Project Navigator (*not* the files, just the duplicate reference!) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and know what I did.

I started a new project and imported all the files from the old project.

Viola!

Answer (score 0):

In xcode, on the build results page, right click the error line and choose "Open These Latest Results as Transcript Text File". This will open the **real** xcode output log, which should contain a better description of the error then was previously seen.

Note:  This shows more information then the Build Results page alone.